# How to i get Events previous and next Event in contao detail page and list page ? f.e < Previous Event | Current Event ( id - 4) | Next Event >

Tags: contao

How to i get Events previous and next Event in contao detail page and list page ? f.e < Previous Event | Current Event ( id - 4) | Next Event

> Blockquote

Answer (score 0):

There is no extension for Contao 3 that I know of. However, you could do the following.

Insert the following PHP code at the top of your `event_full` template:

```php
<?php

$this->getEventUrl = function($objEvent)
{
  global $objPage;
  return \Controller::generateFrontendUrl($objPage->row(), '/' . $objEvent->alias, null, true );
};

$objNextEvent = \CalendarEventsModel::findOneBy(
  array("startDate > ?", "published = '1'", "pid = ?"), 
  array($this->startDate, $this->pid), 
  array('order' => 'startDate ASC'));
$objPreviousEvent = \CalendarEventsModel::findOneBy(
  array("startDate < ?", "published = '1'", "pid = ?"), 
  array($this->startDate, $this->pid), 
  array('order' => 'startDate DESC'));

?>
```

This will try to fetch the previous and next event in the most simple way.

Insert the following somewhere in your `event_full` template (e.g. before the last closing `</div>`:

```php
<?php if ($objPreviousEvent || $objNextEvent): ?>
  <div class="pagination">
    <?php if ($objPreviousEvent): ?>
    <div class="prev">
      <a href="<?= $this->getEventUrl( $objPreviousEvent ) ?>" title="<?= $objPreviousEvent->title ?>">
        &laquo;&nbsp;<?= $objPreviousEvent->title ?>
      </a>
    </div>
    <?php endif ?>
    <?php if ($objNextEvent): ?>
    <div class="next">
      <a href="<?= $this->getEventUrl( $objNextEvent ) ?>" title="<?= $objNextEvent->title ?>">
        <?= $objNextEvent->title ?>&nbsp;&raquo;
      </a>
    </div>
    <?php endif ?>
  </div>
<?php endif ?>
```

This will echo the URLs to the previous and next events within some HTML code.

There are some drawbacks:

- the code above does not consider the `start` and `end` fields
- this will only show the previous and next event of the same calendar (otherwise the target URL might be wrong)
- this will only work with an enabled `auto_item` parameter

**Update:** I have created a Github Gist here: https://gist.github.com/fritzmg/aa4632be2231d77e7d6ec0e5e0a854ae